# Mui datepicket, значение инпута изменяется вне зависимости от моего value

Tags: reactjs, datepicker, mui

Использую mui datepicker и столкнулся с проблемой. Передаю onChange и value из нужного компонента в datepicker и использую его там. Но, когда выбираю дату в календаре, то мое value не меняется, по нужным мне причинам. Но значение в инпуте изменяется, что сбивает с толку, как мне сделать так, чтобы отображалось мое значение value?

```
value={value}
    onChange={newDate => {
        onChange && onChange(newDate as Date);
        }
    }
```

Уже пробовал достать инпут через реф и туда дату свою пихать, на мнгновение вижу свою дату в useEffect, но потом она меняется на выбранную в календаре и в инпуте выбранная дата не равна моему value, которое приходит извне